# Composition of Möbius Transformation to Identity

Tags: function-and-relation-composition, mobius-transformation

Let $f(x) = \frac{ax+b}{cx+d}$ with $x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \left \{ -\frac{d}{c} \right \} $ be the Möbius Transformation. Find all $a,b,c,d$ such that
$$ \underbrace{f \circ f \circ \dots \circ f}_{n \text{ times}} = \text{id}.$$
My professor and I came to the conclusion that you probably can't write down nice forms depending on $n$. (The case $n=3$ gives a complicated solution.)

However, can you think of any "good" condition or any meaningful progress towards this problem? Feel free to change it a little - it should just be approximately this problem!

(Note that it's easy to find a solution $a,b,c,d$ that works for all $n$. The problem is to find all solutions.)

Comment: I am going to say something very basic, forgive me if you already know. Möbius transformations can be written as projective transformations of $P^1(\mathbb C)$ and as such, represented as matrices. Therefore the composition of two of them *should* be represented as the product of two matrices. This would reduce your problem to the algebraic one of finding all idempotent matrices in $GL_2(\mathbb C)$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_transformation#Projective_matrix_representations

Comment: [Exact same question here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1921798/8157) (the answer there seems to be weaker than the present one) [and here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1659401/8157)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NOTATION**. We denote $f^{\circ n}:=f\circ f\circ \ldots \circ f$.

I cannot find a "pointwise" condition on $a,b,c,d$. (**EDIT**: see bottom of the post for such a condition, due to Will Sawin). However if we regard the matrix 
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d\end{bmatrix},$$ 
then [interpreting the Möbius transformation as a projective transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_transformation#Projective_matrix_representations) we see that the given Möbius transformation sastisfies $f^{\circ n}=\mathrm{id}$ if and only if $A^n$ is a scalar multiple of $I=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$. As shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/600745/8157) such matrices are necessarily diagonalizable, and the equation 
$$
A^n=zI$$
shows that the eigenvalues $\lambda_1, \lambda_2$ of $A$ must satisfy 
$$\lambda_1^n=\lambda_2^n=z.$$

> **Conclusion**. The condition $f^{\circ n} =\mathrm{id}$ for the Möbius transformation represented by the invertible matrix $A=\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix}$ is equivalent to $A$ being diagonalizable and the eigenvalues $\lambda_1, \lambda_2$ of $A$ satisfying $\lambda_1^n=\lambda_2^n$.

**EDIT**. A necessary condition for $f^{\circ n}=\mathrm{id}$ is the following: 
$$\tag{1}
\frac{(a+d)^2}{ad-bc}=2(1+\cos\theta),\quad \theta=\frac{2\pi}{n}k,\ k\in\mathbb Z.$$ 
If $k\ne 0 \mod n$, the condition is also sufficient. Otherwise, it is not, and the necessary and sufficient condition is that (1) holds *and* $A$ is diagonalizable.

*Proof*. This is due to Will Sawin. Letting $\lambda_1, \lambda_2$ denote the eigenvalues of $A$, we have 
$$ 
\frac{(a+d)^2}{ad-bc} = \frac{\lambda_1}{\lambda_2}+\frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1}+2,$$ 
which equals $2+2\cos\theta$ precisely when $\lambda_1/\lambda_2 = e^{2\pi i \frac k n}$, that is, $\lambda_1^n=\lambda_2^n$. If $k\ne 0 \mod n$, then $\lambda_1\ne \lambda_2$ and this automatically implies that $A$ is diagonalizable. Therefore $f^{\circ n}=\mathrm{id}$ because of the characterization proven above.

On the other hand, the matrix $A=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$ satisfies (1) with $k=0$ and $$A^n= \begin{bmatrix} 1 & n\\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix},$$ so it cannot satisfy $A^n=A$ for any $n>1$. Notice that $A$ is not diagonalizable.

To conclude, we note that in the case $k\ne 0\mod n$, we need to manually add to (1) the assumption that $A$ is diagonalizable to ensure that $f^{\circ n}=\mathrm{id}$ holds. $\square$

Comment: We have $(a+d)^2/(ad-bc)= (\lambda_1+\lambda_2)^2 / (\lambda_1\lambda_2) = 2  + \lambda_1 \lambda_2^{-2} + \lambda_2 \lambda_1^{-1}$, which is equal to $2 + 2 \cos \theta$ for some $\theta$ of the form $2 \pi k /n$, $k$ an integer, if and only if $\lambda_1/\lambda_2= e^{2\pi k i /n}$ for some integer $k$.

Comment: @WillSawin: Thank you, I have incorporated your nice remark into the answer.